# Do the migration stats show rejection rates for posts migrated *away* from a site?

Tags: support, moderator-tools

I think it's a bit unlikely for us to have a perfect migration record, given that our inbound migration paths are not so hot.

> [image: We rejected 4/9 inbound migration, yet our 12 outbound migrations were all accepted?]

While it's definitely understandable from a technical viewpoint, it'd be *silly* if outbound migration stats didn't show rejection rate for outbound migration, given that it's all a site moderator has control on.

It's that, or outbound migration rejection stats are already shown and we're just really awesome at it. A conclusion I will gladly accept :P

Comment: While this would be nice, and balpha gave you your current stats, I've taken to asking the mods on the other sites in TL from time to time for the info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does indeed only show the rejection stats for inbound migrations. I see your point about it being just as (or even more) interesting to see the outbound stats; that's just not as easy from a technical perspective. We'll have a look.

For what it's worth, your record is *almost* flawless; of those stats you see, only one question on gamedev counts as rejected (because it was closed as a dupe).

Comment: Closed as dupe counts as rejected? That seems wrong; we tell people to migrate all the time so we can immediately merge